# Convert statsmodel table to latex style .png with python

Tags: python, latex, sympy, statsmodels, pdflatex

I think I am quite close to solve a problem a lot of statsmodel users had in the past. However, my nonexistent latex experience is slowing down my progress by a lot. :D

Let's jump directly into the problem:
In the following I am using the example dataset from https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/regression.html.

The output is therefore the following regression table:
 [OLS Regression Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqzyl.png)

I have tried several packages to convert the output to a latex style .png. The most promising method seems to be to use the sympy.printing.preview.preview function:

In:

```
from sympy.printing.preview import preview

preamble = "\\documentclass[12pt]{article}\n" \
           "\\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,amsfonts}\\begin{document}"

preview(res.summary().as_latex(), output='png', filename='output.png', preamble=preamble)
```

Out:
[Latex style .png 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsBiF.png)

As you can see, the second and third table of the regression as well as the warning below the table are not in line with the first table.

To fix this, I have tried to use the tabularx package as you can see in the following:

```
preamble = "\\documentclass[12pt]{article}\n" \
           "\\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,amsfonts, tabularx}\\begin{document}"

preview(res.summary().as_latex().replace("\\begin{tabular}", "\\begin{tabularx}
{\\textwidth}").replace("\\end{tabular}", "\\end{tabularx}"), output='png', filename='output.png', preamble=preamble)
```

Output:
[Latex style .png 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMggJ.png)

The horizontal lines of table two and three are aligned with the ones of table one, however the input of the table as well as the warning aren't.

Does anybody know how to continue from here? How can I get the original output table in a latex style saved as a .png with python?

Thank you guys in advance!

**Edit1:**

Since `res.summary().as_latex()` outputs the code shown at the end of the post, I have managed to align the tables more or less manually with:

```
preview(res.summary().as_latex().replace("\\begin{tabular}", "\\begin{tabularx}{20cm}").replace("\\end{tabular}", "\\end{tabularx}").replace("{lclc}", "{>{\hsize=.3\hsize}X >{\hsize=.2\hsize}X >{\hsize=.3\hsize}X >{\hsize=.2\hsize}X}").replace("{lcccccc}", "{XXXXXX p{3.6cm}}"), output='png', filename='output.png', preamble=preamble)
```

The [new Output looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVCO1.png). This shouldn't and can't be the **final solution**, therefore I would like to expand the question if somebody knows a more dynamic (non-manual) way to do this.

Full **latex code** of the three tables:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lclc}
\toprule
\textbf{Dep. Variable:}    &        y         & \textbf{  R-squared:         } &     0.416   \\
\textbf{Model:}            &       OLS        & \textbf{  Adj. R-squared:    } &     0.353   \\
\textbf{Method:}           &  Least Squares   & \textbf{  F-statistic:       } &     6.646   \\
\textbf{Date:}             & Thu, 04 Feb 2021 & \textbf{  Prob (F-statistic):} &  0.00157    \\
\textbf{Time:}             &     18:38:15     & \textbf{  Log-Likelihood:    } &   -12.978   \\
\textbf{No. Observations:} &          32      & \textbf{  AIC:               } &     33.96   \\
\textbf{Df Residuals:}     &          28      & \textbf{  BIC:               } &     39.82   \\
\textbf{Df Model:}         &           3      & \textbf{                     } &             \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
               & \textbf{coef} & \textbf{std err} & \textbf{t} & \textbf{P$> |$t$|$} & \textbf{[0.025} & \textbf{0.975]}  \\
\midrule
\textbf{x1}    &       0.4639  &        0.162     &     2.864  &         0.008        &        0.132    &        0.796     \\
\textbf{x2}    &       0.0105  &        0.019     &     0.539  &         0.594        &       -0.029    &        0.050     \\
\textbf{x3}    &       0.3786  &        0.139     &     2.720  &         0.011        &        0.093    &        0.664     \\
\textbf{const} &      -1.4980  &        0.524     &    -2.859  &         0.008        &       -2.571    &       -0.425     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{lclc}
\textbf{Omnibus:}       &  0.176 & \textbf{  Durbin-Watson:     } &    2.346  \\
\textbf{Prob(Omnibus):} &  0.916 & \textbf{  Jarque-Bera (JB):  } &    0.167  \\
\textbf{Skew:}          &  0.141 & \textbf{  Prob(JB):          } &    0.920  \\
\textbf{Kurtosis:}      &  2.786 & \textbf{  Cond. No.          } &     176.  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%\caption{OLS Regression Results}
\end{center}

Notes: \newline
 [1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

Comment: The challenge is that `to_latex()` returns 3 different tables, and so it won't be easily possible to align them.  You might need to parse out the lines and reassemble them in a new table with some additional work.

Comment: Hello Kevin. Thank you for your answer. I have included an edit to the post, where I have managed to do it manually. Do you know how to do stuff like that dynamically, so without setting the length for each output?